# How read ChipID from several FT232?

Tags: delphi, ftdi

I'm have a problem with FT232. I'm writing in Delphi. I need to read ChipID from several FT232. I downloaded the file FTChipID.pas from 
http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/FTDIChip-ID.htm

This is fragment my code:

```
procedure TForm1.CheckComID;
var
  myChipID: array[0..10] of Longword;
  length: DWord;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  chipID.GetNumDevices(@length);

 for i := 0 to length-1 do begin
     chipID.GetDeviceChipID( i, @myChipID[i]);
     Memo1.Lines.Add('Device'+IntToStr(i) + ' ' + IntTohex(mychipID[i]));
  end;
end;
```

The effect is that in Memo1, all read values are the same :/.

For example:

I'm connect three FT232 and the result in Memo1 is:

```
Device0 418CF92B
Device1 418CF92B
Device2 418CF92B
```

Can anyone help me ? Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: I can't see any obvious mistake. What status does the `GetDeviceChipID` function call return?

Comment: I checked and I have 0 at each read, i.e. FT_OK. It looks like it's okay and the values are bad :/

Comment: Aren't those devices some _chinese clones_ :)? Have you checked those IDs with some ready made tool?

Comment: Could these values be VID/PID combinations (the same vendor, same model)?

Comment: These are definitely not clones! when only one ft232 chip is connected, each of them has a different ChipID. It seems to me that this GetDeviceChipID function does not switch to checking the next FT232. It works like FT232 still the same: /

Comment: All FT232 have default VID/PID ---> 0403/6001

Comment: Does their example program show the same ID for each device? i.e. the example, here: http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/FTDIChip-ID/Delphi/Delphi.zip. If so, then it seems you have devices with duplicate ids.

Comment: Is `418CF92B` real ID corresponding to some chip (checked when only one is connected)? Have you tried delays between communication with some devices?

Answer (score 0):

GetDeviceChipID identify the chip used not the usb device. I remember that for a FT232R I would get one value and for a FT231X (which is similar chip) I would get a different number.

If you want to read the id that identify the usb device the property is named Serial Number.

The C# api is OpenBySerialNumber(string serialnumber) if you know the serial number.
Else you can try OpenByIndex(0), OpenByIndex(1), OpenByIndex(2), to discover all the FT232 connected to your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Delphi the latest version?
FTD2XX.DLL is not compatible with the latest version of Delphi.
Currently, I also use FTD2XX.DLL in the latest version of Delphi, but I'm sorting out the functions that work.
Since FT_CreateDeviceInfoList and FT_ReadEE work, I read the EPROM of FT232 directly and search for ChipID etc.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use only FTChipID.ChipID.OpenBySerialNumber("SRNO")

As if you system is having more than one FTDI USB connected and if any COM Port is open you will get incorrect value of GetNumDevices() and your OpenBYIndex() will always fail in that case.